# How do I round up currency values in Java?

Tags: java, currency, rounding

Okay, here's my problem.
Basically I have this problem.

I have a number like .53999999.
How do I round it up to 54 without using any of the Math functions?

I'm guessing I have to multiply by 100 to scale it, then divide? 
Something like that?

---

The issue is with money. let's say I have $50.5399999 I know how to get the $50, but I don't have how to get the cents. I can get the .539999 part, but I don't know how to get it to 54 cents.

Comment: I suggest changing the title to something like: "How do I round up currency values in Java?" This way the question is more apropos to people searching for answers - and you will get an up vote from me ;)

Answer (score 20):

I would use something like:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("50.5399999").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

There is a great article called [Make cents with BigDecimal](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2075315/make-cents-with-bigdecimal.html) on [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com) that you should take a look at.

Comment: I liked your first response better.

Comment: BigDecimal is indeed the answer

Comment: What's the trade of with the first answer?: int i = ( int ) ( x + .5 )

Comment: not sure what you are asking? I changed my answer because the question was edited.

Answer (score 16):

You should use a decimal or currency type to represent money, not floating point.

Comment: Yes, floating point currency storage can lead to very bad things after a bit of computation.

Comment: This is important!  Never use floating point numbers for money!  Bad things _will_ happen!

Comment: Store currency as a long (number of cents)

Comment: What about fractional cents (calculations involving percents of money may give rise to fractional cents).

Comment: @Albert: Most currency types can handle this.  Otherwise use another decimal type, or long number of 1/100 cents.

Answer (score 8):

#### Math with money is more complex than most engineers think (over generalization)

If you are doing currency calculations, I think you may be delving into problems that seem simple at their surface but are actually quite complex. For instance, rounding methods that are a result of business logic decisions that are repeated often can drastically affect the totals of calculations.

- I would recommend looking at the [Java Currency class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) for currency <s>formatting</s>.
- Also having a look at this [page on representing money](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13) in java may be helpful.

If this is homework, showing the teacher that you have thought through the real-world problem rather than just slung a bunch of code together that "works" - will surely be more impressive.

On a side note, I initially was going to suggest looking at the implementation of the Java math methods in the source code, so I took a look. I noticed that Java was using native methods for its rounding methods - just like it should.

However, a look at BigDecimal shows that there is Java source available for rounding in Java. So rather than just give you the code for your homework, I suggest that you look at the BigDecimal private method doRound(MathContext mc) in the Java source.

Comment: The Currency class doesn't actually do any formatting, nor does it store any monetary values; it's just holds a little bit of information about the properties of a currency, of which getDefaultFractionDigits() is the only really relevant one here (and duplicates information in the question anyway).

Answer (score 7):

If 50.54 isn't representable in double precision, then rounding won't help.

If you're trying to convert 50.53999999 to a whole number of dollars *and a whole number of cents*, do the following:

```
double d = 50.539999; // or however many 9's, it doesn't matter
int dollars = (int)d;
double frac = d - dollars;
int cents = (int)((frac * 100) + 0.5);
```

Note that the addition of 0.5 in that last step is to round to the *nearest* whole number of cents.  If you always want it to round *up*, change that to add 0.9999999 instead of 0.5.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you not want to use any Math functions?

```
static long round(double a)
```

-Returns the closest long to the argument.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

To represent money I would take the following advice instead of re-inventing the wheel:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13

Comment: The problem is that we have not covered anyting regarding 'static' and 'round'.

The issue is with money.
let's say I have $50.5399999
I know how to get the $50, but I don't have how to get the cents.
I can get the .539999 part, but I don't know how to get it to 54 cents.

Comment: I added a note about representing money with Java

Answer (score 3):

Try storing your currency as number of cents (you could abstract this to number of base curreny units) with a long.

Edit: Since this is homework, you may not have control over the types. Consider this a lesson for future projects

```
long money = 5054;

long cents = money % 100;
long dollars = money / 100; // this works due to integer/long truncation

System.out.printf("$%d.%02.d", dollars, cents);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the number .535 and compare that with your original number to see if you'll round up or down. Here's how you get .535 from .53999999 (should work for any number):

```
num = .53999999;
int_num = (int)(num * 100); // cast to integer, however you do it in Java
compare_num = (int_num + 0.5) / 100;
```

`compare_num` would be .535 in this case. If `num` is greater than or equal to `compare_num`, round up to `int_num + 1`. Otherwise round down simply to `int_num`.

Comment: At those who assume "round up" means "always round up" ... This could be the case, yes.  Just replace 0.5 in @Ruten's example with 0.9999999...  Or, negate and round down, then negate again.

Answer (score 0):

Sean seems to have it, except, if you want to impose proper rules then you may want to throw in an if statement like so:

```
double value = .539999;
int result = (int) (value*100);
if(((value*100)%result)>.5)
    result++;
```

Comment: i wish people would comment why they downvote, i dont see how this isnt acceptable code...

Comment: @gnomed:  agreed: downvote should get a comment.  It looks fine to me, so one up.  only improvement would be to package this as a function with the precision passed as a param.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use long for rounding a double value. It won't matter for small numbers but could make a difference.

```
double d = 50.539999;
long cents = (long)(d * 100 + 0.5);
double rounded = cents/100;
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you trying to do? Are you always trying to go to two digits? Or are you always trying to fix things like 99999 at the end no matter what?

According to the comments, it is in fact the former: rounding to dollars and cents. So indeed just `round(100*a)/100` is what you want. (The latter would be much more complicated...)

Finally, if you just want to extract the cents part, the following would work:

```
dollars_and_cents = round(100*a)/100
cents = (dollars_and_cents-(int)dollars_and_cents)*100
```

(or does java just have `frac`? In which case the last line would just be `frac(dollars_and_cents)*100`.

Comment: I commented on the first reply on what exactly I am trying to do.
"The issue is with money. let's say I have $50.5399999 I know how to get the $50, but I don't have how to get the cents. I can get the .539999 part, but I don't know how to get it to 54 cents."